# Flutter: Screen Navigation and Scaffold transition animation

Tags: flutter, navigation, scaffold

I'm new to flutter.  I made a test project that navigates between two screens:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nspHh.jpg

The code uses Navigation.push and Navigation.pop method.  However, I find the animation not to my liking.  Is it possible for the appBar at the top to "stay put"?  Either the transition animation is disabled so it looks instantaneous or have the Navigation.push() method apply only to the body of the Scaffold (if that's possible).

Thanks!